# Controller function not call in Angular module md-data-table

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-material

As per documentation of "md-data-table". I have implemented datatable. But function getDesserts is not calling.

Service code is as below

```
return {
    'getPagingData': function (params) {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        console.log("Get Paging Service...");
        pagination.getPagingData(params,function (response) {
            defered.resolve(response);
        },
        function (error) {
            defered.reject(error);
    });
    return defered.promise;
    }
}
```

And Controller code is as below

```
$scope.selected = [];

$scope.queryy = {
    order: 'name',
    limit: 5,
    page: 1,
    className :"Sla"
};

function success(desserts) {
    alert("d");
    $scope.desserts = desserts;
}

$scope.getDesserts = function () {
    alert("d");
    //$scope.promise = $nutrition.desserts.get($scope.query, success).$promise;
    $scope.promise =  pagingService.getPagingDataHttp($scope.queryy, success).$promise;
};
```

My html code is as below

```
<!-- exact table from live demo -->
<md-table-container>
    <table md-table md-row-select multiple ng-model="selected" md-progress="promise">
        <thead md-head md-order="query.order" md-on-reorder="getDesserts">
            <tr md-row>
                <th md-column md-order-by="nameToLower"><span>Dessert (100g serving)</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody md-body>
            <tr md-row md-select="dessert" md-select-id="name" md-auto-select ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data">
                <td md-cell>{{dessert.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</md-table-container>

<md-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit" md-limit-options="[5, 10, 15]" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{desserts.count}}" md-on-paginate="getDesserts" md-page-select></md-table-pagination>
```

After this implementation, getDessert function in controller is not being
 called. Kindly guide me